# Value getting lost in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

One of the values from my webpage is not making it to the controller.

I have an `OrderDetailsModel` model class:

```cs
public class OrderDetailsModel
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In my `PartsInformationController`, I have a small bit of IBM DB2 SQL  to get the values:

```cs
public class PartsInformationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DescriptionTicket(string sdsrno)
    {
        var daorno = "";
        var sql = $@"
SELECT DAORNO
FROM {ViewBag.Library}.DLRINVAPF
WHERE DASRNO='{sdsrno}'";

        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, new OleDbConnection(_conn)))
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    daorno = $"{reader[0]}".Trim();
                }
            }
        }

        var model = new OrderDetailsModel()
        {
            SerialNumber = sdsrno,
            OrderNumber = daorno
        };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

In the `DescriptionTicket.cshtml` view, I have:

```html
@model Website1.Models.OrderDetailsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DescriptionTicket";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div id="grid-split">
    <div>
        <h1 class="center">PARTS SEARCH BY KEYWORD</h1>
        <label>
            Search By Keyword <input type="text" id="keyword" value="" /><button onclick="generateByKeyword()">Search</button>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="searchResults">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function generateByKeyword() {
        var partByKey = '@Url.Action( "PartByKey", "PartsInformation")';
        var orderNumber = 
        $('#searchResults').load(partByKey,
            {
                Keyword: $('#keyword').val(),
                Serial: @Model.OrderNumber,
                dealerID: @Model.DealerID
            });
    }
</script>
```

[image: screenshot of webpage]

When I click the "Search" button, both `keyword` and `dealerID` have their values, but the `orderNumber` parameter is null:

```cs
public ActionResult PartByKey(string keyword, string orderNumber, string dealerID)
{
    var model = new PartSearchModel()
        {
            DealerID = dealerID,
            OrderNumber = orderNumber,
        };
}
```

What am I missing?

Is there a better way to write this other than with Javascript?

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using js rather than just post from a html form?

Comment: @JBatstone - it is an existing website. I have to justify any changes I make. I can make them, but I just have to have a reason to submit for the reviewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the `DescriptionTicket.cshtml` view.

It should have been as follows:

```html
    function generateByKeyword() {
        var partByKey = '@Url.Action( "PartByKey", "PartsInformation")';
        $('#searchResults').load(partByKey,
            {
                Keyword: $('#keyword').val(),
                orderNumber: @Model.OrderNumber,
                dealerID: @Model.DealerID
            });
    }
```

because the Controller uses the `orderNumber` variable.